# python and serial ports - regular or fancy text?

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, usb

I am using a combination of FTDI usb driver and python-serial library to communicate with a USB led light.

When I am writing a value to the serial port (to turn the. Light on) can I pass regular ASCII text or does it need to be the hex equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular ASCII works for me with our FTDI cables. You may also need to terminate the string with a `\n`.